# CheckboxSelectMultiple validation error when submitting the form on Django

Tags: django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
      OPTION_CHOICES = (('a','a'),('b','b'))
      option = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=OPTION_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model=MyModel
            fields=['option']
            widgets = {'option':CheckboxSelectMultiple(),}
```

When I try to submit the form, I have validation error and can't submit it. When I chance `CheckboxSelectMultiple` to `RadioSelect` it works just fine. So how can I fix this using `checkboxSelectMultiple`

Comment: What does the error say? What do you think get saved in the option fields when you choose both 'a' and 'b'? Your field should accept more than one option. You can change the field name from option to opntion*s* and make it a many to many field so it can strore (relations to) multiple objects.

Comment: OR do something bitwise https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield

Comment: @allcaps the error says **Select a valid choice. [u'a'] is not one of the available choices.**

Comment: Yep, [] is a list. And there is no option that is a list. You just can't store a list in a field that accepts a single char. See my other comments.

Comment: @allcaps `ManyToManyField` requires me to to specify a relation to another Model that I don't have, Is there any other solution ?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do. With multiple choice widget you want to store multiple values in a field. Your current field does NOT accept multiple values. So switch to a field type that does. You have a lot to choose from, what works for you depends on your requirements. I cant tell. So yes create that extra model OR switch to bitwise OR create two boolean fields OR write your own custom field OR use an ArrayField (postgres) OR ...

Answer (score 0):

```
option = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=OPTION_CHOICES)
```

Only accepts a single char. By submitting the form with multiple choice widget you try to store a list:

```
[u'a']
```

This of course will result in an error:

```
Select a valid choice. [u'a'] is not one of the available choices.
```

Again: `'a'` or `'b'` are strings and valid choices, `[u'a']` is a list an is not valid.

To store lists (or multiple relations) you should pick some other field type. What field type exactly depends on your project requirements. There is not enough info to give you advice what to use.