# Django Form Validation Error?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to run and validate a form but having some problem. Instead of displaying the form it renders the template which I put to display when the form is not valid.

Here is my **Model**:

```
class Preference(models.Model):
    CLASS_CHOICES = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3')]
    BOARD_CHOICES = [('C', 'CBSE'), ('I', 'ICSE'), ('S', 'State Board')]
    SLOT_CHOICES = [('M', 'Morning'), ('A', 'AfterNoon'), ('E', 'Evening')]
    SUBJECT_CHOICES = [('H', 'HINDI'), ('M', 'MATH'), ('E', 'ENGLISH')]
    LOCATION_CHOICES = [('M', 'My Home'), ('T', 'I am willing to travel')]
    GENDER_CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('B', 'Both are Fine')]
    Class = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CLASS_CHOICES, default='1', blank=False)
    Board = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BOARD_CHOICES, default='C', blank=False)
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)
    Frequency = models.IntegerField(default=7)
    Slot = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SLOT_CHOICES, default='E', blank=False)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    Travel = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    Contact = models.IntegerField(default=100)
```

Here is my **form**:

```
class PreferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Preference
        fields = ['Class', 'Board', 'Subject', 'Frequency', 'Slot', 'Location', 'Gender', 'Address',
                  'Travel', 'Name', 'Contact']
        widgets = {
               'Board': forms.RadioSelect(),
               'Subject': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
               'Slot': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
               'Location': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
               'Gender': forms.RadioSelect()}
```

And here is my **view**:

```
def pref2(request):
    form = PreferenceForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        prefer = form.save(commit=False)
        prefer.save()
        return HttpResponse('Thank You!')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, 'website/tutors.html')
```

When I run the app, it renders the 'tutors.html' template without showing the form and `form.errors` display no error.

All help/suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show the `tutors.html` please.

Comment: @nik_m          Right now it just contain <h1>ERROR!!</h1>

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT]: The validation error you get is explained very well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558414/checkboxselectmultiple-validation-error-when-submitting-the-form-on-django). In order to make it work, you should add 3 more models:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    SUBJECT_CHOICES = [('H', 'HINDI'), ('M', 'MATH'), ('E', 'ENGLISH')]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Slot(models.Model):
    SLOT_CHOICES = [('M', 'Morning'), ('A', 'AfterNoon'), ('E', 'Evening')]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SLOT_CHOICES, default='E', blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    LOCATION_CHOICES = [('M', 'My Home'), ('T', 'I am willing to travel')]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, in your `Preference` model, change it to:

```
class Preference(models.Model):
    CLASS_CHOICES = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3')]
    BOARD_CHOICES = [('C', 'CBSE'), ('I', 'ICSE'), ('S', 'State Board')]
    GENDER_CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('B', 'Both are Fine')]

    Class = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CLASS_CHOICES, default='1', blank=False)
    Board = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BOARD_CHOICES, default='C', blank=False)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
    Frequency = models.IntegerField(default=7)
    slots = models.ManyToManyField(Slot)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    Travel = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    Contact = models.IntegerField(default=100)
```

Also, please, rename your fields to lower case (`address` instead of `Address`). First-letter-uppercase is used for Class names.
After that, run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` to apply the changes.

[END EDIT]

It seems that you do not display your form in your `tutors.html` template. That is, you're not taking in advantage the `PreferenceForm` class you just made.

So, inside the `tutors.html`, write this:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit_preference">
</form>
```

But this will not work alone. You must pass the `form` variable from the `pref2` view to your template (in order for `{{ form }}` to be populated).

Change to:

```
return render(request, 'website/tutors.html', locals())
```

Also, the

```
prefer = form.save(commit=False)
prefer.save()
```

is reduntant. Since there is no data manipulation between these two lines (i.e you're not modifying the `prefer` form in some way), you can just make it one, like this:

```
prefer = form.save()
```

Comment: I changed "return render(request, 'website/tutors.html')" to "return HttpResponse('Some Problem'). So it now displays 'Some problem' instead of displaying form.

Comment: No. You should't make that change. You should change `return render(request, 'website/tutors.html')` to `return render(request, 'website/tutors.html', locals())`

Comment: On changing it to "return render(request, 'website/pref2.html', {'form': form})" it displays the form but instead of  saving data in database and showing 'thank you' it displays the form again on clicking submit.

Comment: Did the console printed any errors (cause of the `print(form.errors)`)?

Comment: For the models which i have set widget to forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple() It display the error "Select a valid choice. [&#39;M&#39;] is not one of the available choices.". On changing it to Radioselect() problem is solved. But I want to display checkbox.

Comment: Because it already explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558414/checkboxselectmultiple-validation-error-when-submitting-the-form-on-django) very well, I would suggest you should change `Subject`, `Slot` and `Location` fields from `CharField` into `ManyToManyField`. This requires, of course, to create separate models, for each of them. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I will try to do it. Thanks a lot for your help.